# Pandas : Is there a way to count the number of occurrences of values in a given column which contains dictionaries values in the cells?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, count

I have a df column where each cell contais a dictionary, so when I apply value_counts to this column, I obviolsy get the results for the number of occurrencies of each dictionary. But what I need is to get the number of occirrences of the separate values.
a column cells  look something like this:

```
                      col1

1   [{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Mark'}, {'name': 'Susan'}, {'name': 'Mr.Bean'}, {'name': 'The 
   Smiths'}]

2   [{'name': 'Mark'}, {'name': 'Barbara}, {'name': 'Poly'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Nick'}]
```

So basically what I need as result is how many Susans, Johns etc. there are in the entire columns

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You will have to loop through the all the rows in your data

Comment: You want to _count values_? Have you discovered this function? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html It will be useful in generating a [mcve] if you encounter a problem using it.

Comment: Thank you, gents. As I mentioned above, If I apply the value_counts to this column, I will get the counts like [{}....blabla] 45 [{}....blabla] 55, but I need to get John -465 Nick 568 etc. Can't find the solution. There must be a way of doing that

Comment: @bonnenhoodyahoocom could you please accept one of the answer for this question

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, using @jch setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [ [{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Mark'}, {'name': 'Susan'}, {'name': 'Mr.Bean'}, {'name': 'The Smiths'}], \
[{'name': 'Mark'}, {'name': 'Barbara'}, {'name': 'Poly'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Nick'}] ] })


pd.DataFrame(df['col1'].to_list()).stack().str['name'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
John          2
Mark          2
Susan         1
Mr.Bean       1
The Smiths    1
Barbara       1
Poly          1
Nick          1
dtype: int64
```

Let's use pandas DataFrame constructor, `stack` to reshape to single column, then using the selector from `.str` accessor to get the values from dictionaries and lastly `value_counts`.

Comment: Great answer. One of my favorite things about SO is when someone comes over the top of my answer with a better answer. I always learn from those. This answer is one of those. The magical part of your answer is the string accessor part - `.str['name']` - using that to pull a value out of a dictionary. I’m like wow! and what??? I could not find that in the doc – it might be there but I could not find it. I did find that capability in the pandas source – starting with `accessor.py::__getitem__()`, ending in `object_array.py::_str_get()` where I found `if isinstance(x, dict): return x.get(i)`

Comment: @jch Yep, I stumbled upon this when I was trying extract values from a dictionary stored in a dataframe column a while back.  .str[] is equal to .str.get and you found the exact code that lets us access dictionary items.

Comment: Maybe we could get it added to the pandas documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The data is actually a list of dictionaries on each line. You can build a dataframe from each row.  Then the names are contained in a column which can be converted to a list, exploded and then perform a `value_counts` on that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [ [{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Mark'}, {'name': 'Susan'}, {'name': 'Mr.Bean'}, {'name': 'The Smiths'}], \
[{'name': 'Mark'}, {'name': 'Barbara'}, {'name': 'Poly'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Nick'}] ] })

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                                col1
0  [{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Mark'}, {'name': ...
1  [{'name': 'Mark'}, {'name': 'Barbara'}, {'name...
```

value_count :

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x['col1']).squeeze().to_list(), axis=1).explode().value_counts()
```

Output :

```
John          2
Mark          2
Susan         1
Mr.Bean       1
The Smiths    1
Barbara       1
Poly          1
Nick          1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `explode()` function to transform each element of a list-like to a row, replicating the index values. Then we can use `json_normalize` to convert each key in the dictionary to transform it to a column. Then `value_counts()` can be used to count each unique value in the dataFrame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [ [{'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Mark'}, {'name': 'Susan'}, {'name': 'Mr.Bean'}, {'name': 'The Smiths'}], \
                             [{'name': 'Mark'}, {'name': 'Barbara'}, {'name': 'Poly'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Nick'}] ] })
print(pd.json_normalize(df.col1.explode()).value_counts())
```

Result :

```
name      
John          2
Mark          2
Barbara       1
Mr.Bean       1
Nick          1
Poly          1
Susan         1
The Smiths    1
```

If you want to get the count of any one name, say `John`

```
name = 'John'
print(pd.json_normalize(df.col1.explode()).eq(name).sum())
```

Result :

```
2
```