# extract substring between characters

Tags: pandas

string: `{'Price_Min_COR': 21561.32, 'Price_Max_COR': 21600}`

first character: 'Price_Min_COR':

two character: ,

code:`df[df['LEVEL'].isna()==0].LEVEL.str.extract('("Price_Min_COR":.*?)\,')`

result: Nan

need result : 21561.32

how to write regular expression ?

```
Open_Time_s=['2022-04-30 11:05:00+03:00','2022-04-30 11:10:00+03:00', np.nan, np.nan]
dici=[np.nan,np.nan,{'Price_Min_COR': 21561.32, 'Price_Max_COR': 21600},{'Price_Min_COR': 21561.32, 'Price_Max_COR': 21600}]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'OPEN_TIME':Open_Time_s,'dicts':dici})

print(df[df['dicts'].isna()==0].dicts.str.extract(r'Price_Min_COR:(.*)\b,'))
```

Comment: please provide the output of `df.head().to_dict()` as edit to the question

Comment: please using example data

Comment: @mozway   thanks, very need regular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['col1'].str.extract("'Price_Min_COR':\s(.*),")
```

---

## Update

I think you have dictionary instead of a string,

Try this:

```
df['dicts'].str['Price_Min_COR']
```

Output:

```
0         NaN
1         NaN
2    21561.32
3    21561.32
Name: dicts, dtype: float64
```

Comment: maybe it's a subquery .. result Nan

Comment: @максимильин  See update.

Comment: I don't understand how it works

Comment: @максимильин Take a look at the comments from this solution... https://stackoverflow.com/a/72734254/6361531

Answer (score 1):

this should get you the result. use

```
Price_Min_COR.:(.*)\b,
```

```
extract(r'Price_Min_COR.:(.*)\b,')
```

here you can see the result
https://regex101.com/r/HuTuaJ/1

Comment: did not help, the result is Nan

Comment: @максимильин   post the data in text form. i tried the provided string in regex101  . please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i added an example. Look task